# Python generate SOABI/Extension Suffix (pep 3149) for Windows

Tags: python

When I compile a cython-based C-extension on MacOS/Linux, I get a `.so` file with a name like `foo.cpython-37m-darwin.so`. I can get the extension suffix using:

```
import sysconfig
print(sysconfig.get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX'))  # .cpython-37m-darwin.so
print(sysconfig.get_config_var('SOABI'))  # cpython-37m-darwin
```

On windows, where I'm building the C-extensions with msys2-mingw, I get a file named `foo.cp37-win_amd64.pyd`, but `sysconfig.get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX')` returns `.pyd`, and fetching the `SOABI` config var returns `None`.

Is there a way to reliably reconstruct the correct full extension suffix on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `distutils` provides the proper information:

```
import distutils
print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX'))  # .cp37-win_amd64.pyd
```

Comment: On Python 3.9 on Windows I had to change the import line to `import distutils.sysconfig`